# Retrieving JSON from http facebook link

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json

I'm implementing the Graph API in Facebook to retrieve data as JSON from an "https" site.

I'm using the following code

```
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.status === 'connected') { 
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    document.getElementById("statusCheck").innerHTML = accessToken;
                    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' . accessToken, 
                      function(dataJSON){
                        //The rest
                      });       
               }    
             });
```

After this failed I tried to use $.ajax with no datatype specification and parsing the data with  $.parseJSON but no information is retrieved *at all*

My question is really twofold: Is my JSON retrieval the problem or is it the fact that the protocol is "https"?  If it is not possible to use getJSON on an external https protocol, how can I recover the hash of the Facebook friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working. just use +(plus) instead .(dot) before accesstoken.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' **+** accessToken, 
   function(dataJSON){
      console.log(dataJSON);
});
```